# How can I return the IDs of groups that fit a certain complicated condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, I have a table in a PostgreSQL db with basically following columns: compositekey_part, group_id, action_type, version, content. Apart from content all of them are numbers, and the version and compositekey_part column makes up the composite primary key.

What I want to achieve is to return every group ID where there's a record that's content is the same as another record in the same group (based on group_id), and the action_type is 0 for both records.

[image: Here's an example table]

where I'd want it to return the group_id 4532 (and if there were more eligible groups, all of their IDs)

I'm mostly a novice with SQL in general, so while I know the basics, I've had a hard time trying to figure out how to do this. I've been using pgAdmin4 to access and mess around with the DB, using the query tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by`:

```
select group_id, content
from t
group by group_id, content
having count(*) > 1;
```

If you wanted to be sure that `group_id` was not duplicated (given that there can be more than one repeated `content`), then you can use `select distinct` with `group by`:

```
select distinct group_id
from t
group by group_id, content
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Well, I'm baffled how simple the solution is. I added a "where action_type = 0", since that's part of the condition and it gave exactly the answer I was looking for. And I thought the other answer was already much simpler than I expected. I very much overcomplicated things it seems like

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` if you want entire record for which there is duplicate data as follows:

```
Select t.*
  From your_table t
 Where action_type = 0
   And exists 
       (select 1 from your_table tt
         Where tt.group_id = t.group_id
           And tt.content = t.content
           And tt.action_type = 0
           And (tt.compositekey_part<> t.compositekey_part or t.version <> tt.version));
```

Comment: This gives the exact result I want too, so I'm very grateful, though the other answer is simpler, so I ended up using that, but I'm glad I know about `exists` now